# Why is my XMLHttpRequest POST not always making it to the server?

Tags: node.js, http, post, events, xmlhttprequest

I'm making an XMLHttpRequest, posting a string to a nodejs server upon certain user events in the browser, but not every event seems to make it to the server.

Here is basically the function I'm calling for each browser event:

```
function xhr_event(timeStamp){
    xhr=new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open("POST",'/record_event');
    console.log(timeStamp.toString())
    xhr.send(timeStamp.toString())
}
```

where `timeStamp=event.timeStamp`

On the client side, each event logs to console. On the server side, not all events appear to POST. To the best I can tell, lost events are random.

I read about browser caching but I don't think that can be the problem, since each payload has a unique time stamp? Then again I'm not doing any encoding or setting of headers, so maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Try adding `var` before `xhr` like so: `var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest()`.

Comment: @mottek Yes that did seem to solve the problem. Can you explain what's happening?

Comment: Sure. Without the `var`, `xhr` is a global variable. There is a race condition if `xhr_event` gets called twice. If the first call processes the `console.log` command and the second call processes the `xhr=new ...` line at the same time, `xhr` of the first call gets overwriten just before it's `send` method  gets called.

Answer (score 0):

As @mottek mentioned and explained in the comments, adding a `var` (or `let` or `const`) before `xhr` solved the problem.

I didn't realize `xhr=new XMLHTTPRequest()` creates a global variable.

I also got the `post` to work consistently by using `fetch`:

```
fetch('/record_event', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type':'text/plain'
    }
    body: timeStamp.toString()
}
```